# Can't get correct result from my if !=nil statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

Beginner alert!
I have this IF statement in my `user#show` view. I checked if any post for `user_id:7` in rails console, it returns the result **nil**, but when I looked at http://localhost:3000/users/7, I can't see the comment:

> You don't have any post yet. Keep posting!

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<% if @posts != nil %>
<%= link_to "#{post.title}", post_path(post) %>
<% else %>
<p> You don't have any post yet. Keep posting! </p>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is:

```
<% if @posts.present? %>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= link_to "#{post.title}", post_path(post) %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
    <p> You don't have any post yet. Keep posting! </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yeah, first the `@posts` would probably have returned an empty array and in Ruby `[] != nil`

Comment: i.e empty array is not equal to nil

Comment: Second the loop through your `@posts` ought to have been nested under the check for the presence of the posts

Comment: The logic basically is if there are posts available, loop through them, otherwise display the error message

Comment: Your previous approach basically said: loop through each post in posts, if the post is not `nil` show the link, otherwise show the the error.

Comment: The error wasn't shown because the posts is empty, so there was nothing to loop through at all.

Comment: Hey! thanks oreoluwa for clarifying! I really appreciate it. The code works now.  @posts is not nil. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to help. You can accept the answer, if that solved the issue!!

Answer (score 0):

If variable @posts is empty, you can't get `<p> You don't have any post yet. Keep posting! </p>`

`User.find(7).posts` will return a array. `an empty array != nil`

Try this:

```
<% if !@posts.blank? %>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
     <%= link_to "#{post.title}", post_path(post) %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <p> You don't have any post yet. Keep posting! </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `unless ... else ... end` is largely frowned at in the Ruby community. rather use `if ... else ... end`

Comment: @孙悟空, I wouldn't let someone's personal preference influence your code. If it reads well and is maintainable, keep it. In this case I'd opt for either `<% unless @posts.empty? %>` or `<% if @posts %>`.

Comment: @Tass, Actually, with an else clause, unless may be more confusing than the reversed equivalent for a Beginner . i hope my answer is helpful, personal preference is second thing.

Comment: My point is that it's user preference. I've never seen anyone, anywhere say that `unless` is frowned upon. Telling someone new to the language that it's frowned upon isn't a good idea. Show them the tools, teach them how to use them.